SVD of matrix with dimensions
Context: Suppose $\Phi \colon \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ is differentiable. Suppose further that each element $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ has different units, as does each element of $\Phi(\mathbf{x}) \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$. We form the Jacobian of $\Phi(\mathbf{x})$ and compute its SVD:
$$
\mathbf{J}_{\Phi}(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{U}\Sigma \mathbf{V}^{T}
$$
Where do the units go on the right hand side? I believe that the condition $\mathbf{U}^{T}\mathbf{U} = \mathbf{V}^{T}\mathbf{V} = \mathbf{I}$ enforces that each element of $\mathbf{U}$ and $\mathbf{V}$ is dimensionless. This means that $\Sigma$ must carry the units, but there can be $nm$ independent units in $\mathbf{J}_{\Phi}(\mathbf{x})$, but only $r \le \min(n,m)$ singular values to carry them.
What am I missing here? Where do the units go in the SVD decomposition?

The SVD is sensitive to the exact scaling of each variable; if you change units in each variable separately you simply get a different SVD entirely (not a rescaling of the original SVD).

@QiaochuYuan: Forgive me-I'm not sure what you mean by this-I'm not changing the unit in any variable-the units are fixed by the original function $\Phi$.

If the components in the domain have different units, then some of the units have to be inside of $V^T$, just for $V^T x$ to make sense. If you set it up so that the components of $V^T x$ have all the same units, then you can have $\Sigma$ map those to what they'll be in the output, at which point $U$ can be dimensionless. Overall you have some freedom to shuffle these things around. But changing units in one variable will entirely alter the SVD, rather than making some kind of local change, as Qiaochu Yuan said.

(Cont.) That said, you don't really have $mn$ independent dimensions. You could have $mn$ different ones, but they're not freely chosen; instead they're dictated by the choice of the $n$ dimensions in the domain and the $m$ dimensions in the codomain. Specifically, $a_{ij}$ has the dimensions of $y_i/x_j$.

@Ian: If the elements of $V$ are dimensioned how can we ensure the condition $V^{T}V=I$ makes sense?

@user14717 It's not really even a true transpose in this situation. It's an inverse, which happens to be numerically represented by a transpose. But although the numerical values are the same, the units of "$V_{ij}$" and "$(V^T)_{ji}$" are reciprocals, not the same. Changing the units in one component then destroys the unitary structure completely. Again, this is hinting towards the original point that using the SVD when you have different units in each component doesn't really make sense. (But it makes perfect sense when you have different units in the domain and codomain.)

@user14717 Let me put it more bluntly: the SVD is inextricably connected to the Euclidean norm. What does the Euclidean norm even mean when the components of your space don't have the same units?
